# List semi-colons?

Tags: lists, semicolons, colons

> Eleanor Roosevelt played an active political role. She wrote newspaper
>   columns, made speeches and radio broadcasts, traveled widely, and
>   listened to the concerns of women, minorities, and ordinary Americans.

Would it need to be rewritten with ; because it is a list within a list? I just recently learned this concept, and I am still kinda confused on it.

She wrote newspaper

> She wrote newspaper columns, made speeches and radio broadcasts, traveled widely, and
>   listened to the concerns of women; minorities; and ordinary Americans.

Comment: No, it's all commas in the second sentence.

Answer (score 1):

It reads clearly enough with commas.

If you insisted on distinguishing the two types of list then it could be better the other way round as in

> She wrote newspaper columns; made speeches and radio broadcasts; traveled widely; and listened to the concerns of women, minorities, and ordinary Americans.

but I do not think that is an improvement on just commas.

Answer (score 0):

Because the list items are independent clauses, they should be preceded by a colon and separated by semicolons. In your example, this also helps distinguish the comma-separated list as a collection of related concepts.

*Eleanor Roosevelt played an active political role: She wrote newspaper columns; made speeches and radio broadcasts; traveled widely; and listened to the concerns of women, minorities, and ordinary Americans.*